# ClassFormatException when integrating the applet in vaadin project

Tags: java, applet, vaadin

Well, I am using the vaadin AppletIntegration Addon to integrate my sound recorder applet with my vaadin project.
Here is the code :

```
  AppletIntegration applet = new AppletIntegration() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void attach() {
      System.out.println("In attach functions");

      setAppletArchives(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "SoundRecordingJar.jar" }));
      setCodebase(path);
      setAppletClass("AudioApplet.class");

      setWidth("800px");
      setHeight("500px");
    }
  };
  mainWindow.addComponent(applet);
```

When I run it in browser :
It gives me the following exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1008813135 in class file AudioApplet
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I run the same applet with html file, it works fine with no exception. The applet is signed also.

So,
What does this error mean and how to solve it.

Comment: is your browser is using the same jre used by vaadin or its different ?

Comment: Did you try to run jar from command line? (with definition main class)?

Comment: @Sunny My browser is using jre version 1.6.0_35 and vaadin is using jre version 1.6.0_30. So should i make them same?

Comment: Don't think its version issue since both 1.6. Usually `ClassFormatError` you get on corrupted jar file

Comment: @Fess so what can be the reasons possibly which made the jar corrupted. The jar I am using is basically my eclipse project, which I exported in the jar form. Then I make it sign. It works fine with HTML file, but gives that error when integrating with vaadin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spent some time trying to get this to work w/ a simple applet to display the java version the browser is using. Just a basic Vaadin servlet w/ just the AppletIntegration instance on the main page, no other real stuff going on.

First it was class not found issues, and after fixing that I was left w/ the dreaded "Incompatible magic value 1008813135 in class file ..." message, which I just couldn't seem to get around. Finally I figured it out and thought I would post here, in case someone comes looking...

So this 100881315 magic value is actually

What's not clear on the AppletIntegration page, or even here in the forums, is where exactly the jar(s) should be placed in your war file...

Now anyone who's done some applet coding knows that the CODEBASE is where you are supposed to indicate where the jars are. But in a normal Vaadin servlet, you also have to be aware of what the servlet's url pattern is in the web.xml block.

So normally you'll have a servlet mapping defined as follows in your web.xml file for a Vaadin-based servlet:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AppletTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

So basically you're routing any incoming request, i.e. "/myclasses.jar", through the Vaadin controller, and Vaadin will choke on it and not return your jar file. That was my first attempt that resulted in the 100881315 error...

I had even tried creating an applets folder and setting my CODEBASE to "applets/", but again the same error because the url pattern routes the request through the Vaadin controller which chokes.

So the key is how to return the jar as a resource through the Vaadin controller... If you haven't already guessed, it's accomplished by putting your jar into the VAADIN folder (I got a hint about this through reading the forum thread).

So I created a VAADIN/applets folder, dropped my jar(s) in there, and set my CODEBASE to "VAADIN/applets/" and voila, all is working correctly...

Please, Sami, I'm begging you to add this little nugget of truth onto the Applet Integration page somewhere, at least so others may not have to spend the hours tracking this down that I did...

Comment: Great, that you solved it. Paradoxically, this morning I responded on other error and pointed on `servlet-mapping` problem. But there was `Servlet`. Good to know about magic value on this type of issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your magic value is  1008813135

```
int magic = 1008813135   ;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(magic);
System.out.println(new String(b.array()));
```

Output: `<!DO`

The class file seems to be corrupted. The "magic value" are the first 4 bytes in the file and they should always be 0xCA 0xFE 0xBA 0xBE.
Instead, they are 0x3C 0x21 0x44 0x4F (1008813135 converted to hex). They correpond to the ASCII sequence

Try to clear your java cache or try to use other PC for debug purposes.

It may be that their free service does not allow applets.

Comment: Your getting some sort of HTML response rather than your actual jar file. [take a look on the same problem, here]{https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1091143?_19_threadView=flat}

Comment: I cleared cache and also debug the my applet on other PC, but same result. What are the reasons which causes the class file to corrupt. And how to deal with them?

Comment: How did you signed your jar? with ant? What is content of your jar?

Comment: thanks, that URL worked. I Created a folder in VAADIN folder which is WebContent folder and placed my jars and .class files there. And ALHAMDULILLAH, every thing is working now.

Comment: I signed my jar by first creating the keystore, then using that keystore, i signed my jar with jarsigner tool. My jar file is basically my exported eclipse project in the form of jar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your magic code looks more like the start of a HTML file. `<!DOCTYPE...`. Maybe you should check if the download went wrong (With Firebug, Wireshark or something similar.) This might be the 404-error message.

Comment: I have created my own jar. I have not downloaded it from any where else.